# Docker with Net Core 2.2

Tags: .net, docker

I have followed this tutorial but I can't see my app as container when I type `docker ps`.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#build-and-run-the-docker-image

very simple values net core app

```
$ docker run -it -d -p 5011:5011  aspnetapp
efd62fcad947a70c1309b06eb2270ea321dc9b7d0cdb24c359be9e39cfea7131
```

outputs and exits

```
docker run  -p 5011:5111  --name myapp6 appservice
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {b49b85f8-65a4-44b3-b809-a2e8d79aeb88} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5011 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Error -99 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available'.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://localhost:5011
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Comment: What is the output of `docker ps -a`? Can you get some logs off the container - `docker logs <containerId>`

Comment: Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

Comment: logs has this....

Comment: You can update your question with the log snippet. Also, was the image created correctly? Share the output of `docker images`

Comment: i changed the entrypoint to my apps name and ok but now i cant get a response from localhost:5011

Comment: Is your app within the container running at port 80 or 5011? Get in the container and check if the app is running. `docker exec -it <containerID> /bin/bash` and check if the service is running

Comment: my app runs on 5011

Comment: docker run  -p 80:5111  --name myapp6 appservice
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {b49b85f8-65a4-44b3-b809-a2e8d79aeb88} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5011 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Error -99 EADDRNOTAVAIL address not available'.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://localhost:5011
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Comment: You have mapped it to port 5011 externally. You can now access your app at `localhost:5011` . Assuming your app is internally running on `5111` - For this is what you have mentioned

Comment: tried both not access 5011:5011 not working empty response from request

Comment: localhost didn’t send any data.

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: You will have to check within the container. If your app is responding well. `docker exec -it <containerID> /bin/bash`. Then `curl -iv localhost:5011`. This will confirm that the service is working well within your app.

Comment: winpty docker exec -it   4cd0d9c9648e dotnet run
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

Comment: ls lists dir but dotnet command not running

Comment: Check if you have any service running on the port you specified. Call the API/webservice from within the container.

Comment: 404 not found on port ,, curl -iv localhost:5011$ winpty docker exec -it   4cd0d9c9648e curl -iv localhost:5011
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:5011/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5011 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5011
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: Well, your app is not working. You will have to check your dotnetCore App. Once, you fix this up, you should be able to access it easily from outside the container

Comment: its working on local when i type dotnet run

Comment: Run the same command within the container, followed by curl. Look for the logs

Comment: says dotnet not installed

Comment: You will have to re-visit the build process. Does not look like the image is built correctly.

Comment: what is the workdir i have used /app is that maybe wrong?

Comment: That is where the dll resides/ is copied. Since your error says `dotnet is not installed`, there is surely something you have missed while building the image using the `build` command. You may remove the container and the images and follow the steps over again.

Comment: yeah dockerfile builds for dotnet, i have used docker support menu from visual studio and dockerfile has changed a bit now builds foraspnetcore